# Why is my for loop using push inside a function not working?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to pass a phrase through a function so that every first letter is capitalized and everything else is lower case. I have the following function:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  var array = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= str.length; i++) {
    str = str.split(' ');
    str = str[i].toLowerCase();
    str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1, str.length);
    array = array.push(str);

    return array.push(str);
  }
}

titleCase("SenTencE TesT");
```

Without the for loop the function works and will lowercase everything and then capitalize the first letter of each word.

Comment: You're returning the result of array.push and that's a number

Comment: your return is inside your for loop so it'll only run once also

Comment: Because you put "return array.push(str);" it will return function value on first iteration, but second, third etc. are never going to be fired.

Comment: also the `str = str.split(' ');` with the `i <= str.length` together is confusing, because the loop looks like you want to go through each char in the string but then you split it on the spaces. maybe do `str = str.split(' ');` before the `for` loop also and update `str = str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.substr(1, str.length); array = array.push(str);` to `str[i] = str[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1, str[i].length); array = array.push(str[i]);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[EDIT]**

A lot of ways to do it, but try this...

```
function titleCase(string) {
    var array = string.split(' ');
    var newString = '';
    for (var i = 0; i <= array.length-1; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i].toLowerCase();
        array[i] = array[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + array[i].substr(1, array[i].length);
        newString += array[i] + ' ';
    };
    return newString.trim();
};

console.log( titleCase("SenTencE TesT") );
```

Comment: I get the following error code: TypeError:Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined.

Comment: One follow-up question, why did you modify inside the loop from i<=array.length to i<=array.length-1?

Comment: Because you started your loop at 0, but length starts counting at 1, so to get them lined up you either remove one from the length or start your count at 1, but I prefer 0 because that's the starting index of an array and if you're going to be looping through one, mine as well start where it starts.

Answer (score 0):

1) Don't name your variable array, that is a JavaScript reserved word, you can use "arr" for example.

2) In your code you are splitting the sentence in to an array of words but you are only applying the toLowerCase to the first word.

3) There's a much cleaner way to achieve the result you want:

```
function capitalize(str) {
    return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
} 
console.log( capitalize("sentence TesT") );
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: This works only for the first letter, for instance it converts 'sentence TesT' to 'Sentence test', but what I'm looking for is 'Sentence Test', capitalizing the first letter on the second word as well.

Comment: I guess Waxi answered your question :)